# MySQL error 1064: search query not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I am attempting to write a query for searching on a table, but I am getting the generic 1064 MySQL syntax error. I don't see anything wrong with my query... in fact, I have another query just like it that works fine.

The queries are using an SQL driver in Go, all of the `?` will be converted to values before the query is ran.

This is my error:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT tax.*
>           FROM tax
>           JOIN user_tax
>               ON user_tax.tax_id = tax.id
>           WHERE u' at line 3

For instance, this is the working query:

```
SELECT tax.*
FROM tax
JOIN user_tax
    ON user_tax.tax_id = tax.id
WHERE user_tax.user_id = ?
    AND tax.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND user_tax.deleted_at IS NULL
```

The query above will find all tax records for a given user.

Now I am trying to make the same exact query, except now it is a "search" query. It takes in a search string and looks for it on the `name` and `rate` column of the tax table. This is it:

```
SET @searchString = '%?%';

SELECT tax.*
FROM tax
JOIN user_tax
    ON user_tax.tax_id = tax.id
WHERE user_tax.user_id = ?
    AND tax.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND user_tax.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND tax.name LIKE @searchString
        OR tax.rate LIKE @searchString
```

This is the query in code:

```
var taxes []Tax
err := r.db.Select(&taxes, `
    SET @query = '%?%';

    SELECT tax.*
    FROM tax
    JOIN user_tax
        ON user_tax.tax_id = tax.id
    WHERE user_tax.user_id = ?
        AND tax.deleted_at IS NULL
        AND user_tax.deleted_at IS NULL
        AND tax.name LIKE @query
            OR tax.rate LIKE @query
`, q, userId)
```

Comment: Your interface only allows one query to be passed in.  I would suggest that you learn to use proper parameters for the interface you are using.

Comment: Oh good catch, I meant to put a `?` in the place of the `%s`. Just updated in my code as well as the question. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Also changed `@query` to `@searchString` as that may confuse things, I was not trying to put a query into a query.

Comment: WHERE user_tax.user_id = ? What does this '?' signifies?

Comment: why You're using `?` are You using php pdo or something else to query db?

Comment: The ? will be converted to a value, it represents an integer.

Comment: What language are you using to bind values?

Comment: Updated question with comment on the `?`

Comment: simpy do `(tax.name LIKE ? OR tax.rate LIKE ?)` and pass Your `%s%` as bind parameter

Comment: The `?` will not be converted to a value if it is part of a string. You need to use it as `tax.name LIKE ?` and then bind `'%yourSearchString%'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why to do `SET @query` and pass it inside of it when You can do it by using bind parameter using `?`.

So here is solution (I'm not familiar with `go` so please sorry if something wrong with `go` code):

```
var taxes []Tax
query := "%something%youre%looking%for%"
err := r.db.Select(&taxes, `

    SELECT tax.*
    FROM tax
    JOIN user_tax
        ON user_tax.tax_id = tax.id
    WHERE user_tax.user_id = ?
        AND tax.deleted_at IS NULL
        AND user_tax.deleted_at IS NULL
        AND (
              tax.name LIKE ? 
              OR 
              tax.rate LIKE ?
            )

`, q, userId, query, query)
```

OR try this (I'm not sure if it will work) :

```
var taxes []Tax
query := "something"
err := r.db.Select(&taxes, `
    SET @query = CONCAT('%', ?, '%');

    SELECT tax.*
    FROM tax
    JOIN user_tax
        ON user_tax.tax_id = tax.id
    WHERE user_tax.user_id = ?
        AND tax.deleted_at IS NULL
        AND user_tax.deleted_at IS NULL
        AND (
              tax.name LIKE @query
              OR 
              tax.rate LIKE @query
            )

`, q, query, userId)
```

Comment: Yes, this will work... but is there not a way to not have to pass in `query` N times? What if I have like 30 columns... this is why I was trying to set the variable in the query so I only have to bind to one thing and then re-use it.

Comment: @Lansana are You joking? When You have strict sql query why to think about dynamical moments?

Comment: Well this is coming from someone with minimal SQL experience, but typically in programming I can memoize a value and use that to keep things DRY. I guess that is not how it works in SQL?

Comment: @Lansana sql query is simple think. You can do DRY in `go` part, but query must be strict formed to avoid unexpectedness

Comment: @Lansana you can bind it once in a cross joined subquery and then reuse it.

Comment: @Lansana I'm writing from phone, so please check my second example, hope it will work

Comment: Yes your first example works, I am testing out the second one now. Will accept answer after tests. Thanks for explanation. I am still learning SQL, I suppose I shouldn't bring other programming concepts to it.

Comment: For situations when You need complex things to be DRY there are `stored procedures, stored functions, views` in mysql (;  but it's not recommended to use them everywhere - because it hides business logic from code, so need to care to keep them in easily readable place

Comment: btw for DRY and etc there are ORM's that may have models which can keep repeating things

Comment: Yes, I'm not a fan of ORM's because they can be limiting. [This is the SQL driver](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#namedParams) I am using, apparently there is a way for named parameters. Going to look into that, accepting answer though cause leads me in right direction.

Comment: @Lansana (: `it can be limiting`- not always, also ORM's have ability to pass sql query into model method. But nevermind, as You wish (:

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid binding the same value multiple times, you can bind it in a cross joined subquery once and reuse the value:

```
SELECT tax.*
FROM tax
JOIN user_tax
    ON user_tax.tax_id = tax.id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ? as q) sub
WHERE user_tax.user_id = ?
    AND tax.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND user_tax.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND (tax.name LIKE sub.q
         OR tax.rate LIKE sub.q)
```

Now just bind `%s%` as the first parameter.

Comment: @Lansana I see simple solution that You want. Nice!

Comment: @Lansana - I don't expect any performance issues. The subquery should be executed only once.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel This query gives me an error. `Error 1267: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'` -- using same exact query as you.

Comment: This is bad. Looks like the collation of your connection doesn't match that of the column. I'm not sure what to do in this case, since I always try to use UTF-8 everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax errors reported by MySQL contain the magic words **"check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"** followed by the trailing part of the query that doesn't fit with the leading part that was already parsed and found as correct.

When the part of the query reported in the error message doesn't look incorrect, something is usually missing just before it.

In your case it seems nothing is missing and this leads to a single conclusion: you try to run two queries (correctly separated by `;`) but the library you use to send queries to the server doesn't know that and thinks it is only one query. The same happens on the other side of the connection and the MySQL server simply reports as "Syntax error" everything it founds after the first query (and its terminating `;`).

Don't send two queries in a single call or use a call that allows multiple queries in the same string (if such a call is provided by the library).